Amplitude superposition for different kinds of particles
We have seen that the probability of finding a particle at a particular point is the square of its wave function. In the double slit experiment, we notice that wave functions add up and the resultant function is squared to get probability of finding the particle.  Everywhere we have seen wave functions of like particles superpose. Do different type of particle undergo superposition of wave functions? And if so what is the significance of that resultant wave function? It is like double slit experiment where electron from one slit and photons from other (and photon electron interaction is ignored).

Every photon takes its own path (interferes with itself). Using math of the field some paths are preferred others not, this is the QM and wave function view. If you are in high school stick with the Huygens principle and math … it ends up giving the same pattern.

In the double-slit experiment you have only one wave function of one particle which interferes with itself. The wave functions of independent particles (of the same type or not) do not interfere. This would, e.g., violate the principle of conservation of energy.

Then suppose double slit experiment is carried out with light but not from a single source . We use 2 monochromatic light sources instead of the slit and the light emitted from the sources are also in constant phase always . They shouldn't produce interference pattern according to you .

@Users The wave function of each photon from either light source interferes only with itself. That's not my invention, it is common physics knowledge.

But the optics books say there will be interference pattern if the light from the 2 slits are always in constant phase and monochromatic . It doesn't talk about whether the light is ultimately coming from same source or 2 different sources are placed at the slit.

@Users If you send from different independent sources, one photon only to one slit and another photon only to the other slit, you won't get any interference effects
